# Meteor Accounts add extra fields

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

How do I add extra fields to the Meteor Accounts?

Ex: Profile Picture, Header Picture field etc...

I know how to change the password `Accounts.setUsername(userId, username);`
But how would I add an extra field to the Accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `users` collection in `mongo`. The way to access it is by using

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
    $set:{
        profile: {
            picture: 'url-to-picture'
    }
}});
```

According to [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users), anything that need to be updated by user should be stored under the `profile` key

> profile: an Object which the user can create and update with any data.
>   Do not store anything on profile that you wouldn't want the user to
>   edit unless you have a deny rule on the Meteor.users collection.

Comment: Yeah thanks for editing it because the other key I could not add to the user.